# Uploading multiple files ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am struggling to upload multiple files using ASP.NET (VB).

Below is my code, but I am experiencing an error that says:

> Error 1   'PostedFiles' is not a member of
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload'.

How can I overcome this problem?

Below is my code:

```
For Each postedFile As HttpPostedFile In FileUpload1.PostedFiles
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName)
    postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") & fileName)
Next

Label1.Text = String.Format("{0} files have been uploaded successfully.", FileUpload1.PostedFiles.Count)
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I think you forgot the code

Answer (score 0):

You're using an older version of .NET framework that doesn't have that property. The [`PostedFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx) is available in the current version, but versions [4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.100).aspx) and lower don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is reported widely on Google if you search for the error message.

The PostedFiles property was only introduced in .NET 4.5. It's not stated in your question, but I would assume you are using an earlier version of the framework. You can either upgrade your project to 4.5 (or later), or accept that you can only upload one file in the control, or use a 3rd-party upload widget.

See these links for the difference in the documentation of the FileUpload class between .NET 4.0 and 4.5:

4.0: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.100).aspx

4.5: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx